# Assigning low/med/high labels within subgroup based on a numerical value

Tags: r, dplyr

I currently have the table below.

```
Year   Value
2011   2.1
2011   2.1
2011   3.5
2011   7.8
2011   7.8
2012   1.8
2012   1.8
2012   1.8
2012   5.5
```

I want to categorise the values within each "Year" such that a label of low/med/high is assigned to each row based on the numerical value of "Value", i.e.

```
Year   Value  Cat
2011   2.1    Low
2011   2.1    Low
2011   3.5    Med
2011   7.8    High
2011   7.8    High
2012   1.8    Low
2012   1.8    Low
2012   1.8    Low
2012   5.5    High
```

If there are 3 values within that "Year", then the values will be labelled "Low", "Med", "High" in ascending order. If there are only 2 values within the "Year", the labels will only be "Low" and "High". Every subgroup of "Year" has either only 2 or 3 distinct "Value".

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dense_rank` to get the order of `Value` and use that index to subset category information.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   group_by(Year) %>%
   mutate(Cat = if (n_distinct(Value) > 2)) 
                  c("Low", "Medium", "High")[dense_rank(Value)] else 
                  c("Low","High")[dense_rank(Value)])


#   Year Value Cat   
#  <int> <dbl> <chr> 
#1  2011   2.1 Low   
#2  2011   2.1 Low   
#3  2011   3.5 Medium
#4  2011   7.8 High  
#5  2011   7.8 High  
#6  2012   1.8 Low   
#7  2012   1.8 Low   
#8  2012   1.8 Low   
#9  2012   5.5 High
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L), Value = c(2.1, 2.1, 3.5, 7.8, 7.8, 1.8, 
1.8, 1.8, 5.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: I think it needs to get more complex - "*If there are only 2 values within the "Year", the labels will only be "Low" and "High".*"

Comment: thanks for the solution! I've tried implementing and it returns "NA" values for the "Cat" column. I'm guessing it's because the "Value" column is numerical, so "rank" can't be applied. I can't change it to a factor variable either because I have many "Years" of data. If not there will be too many levels.

Comment: @Desmond `rank` works on numerical values. Can you test it on the data in my post?

Comment: @RonakShah yes it works when I apply it on your dataset. Doesn't work on mine though. Sorry I forgot to mention that I have multiple rows with the same "Year" and "Value". Could that be the reason?

Comment: @Desmond Use `dense_rank` instead. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Updated following change in OP dataset and also just noticed that this OP is tagged `dplyr`. Will take down if OP is only looking for `dplyr` solution

An option using `data.table`

```
DT[order(Year, Value), Cat := if(.N==1L) "L"
    else if(.N==2L) c("L", "H")[rleid(Value)]
    else c("L", "M", "H")[rleid(Value)], 
    Year]
```

output:

```
    Year Value Cat
 1: 2011   2.1   L
 2: 2011   2.1   L
 3: 2011   3.5   M
 4: 2011   7.8   H
 5: 2011   7.8   H
 6: 2012   1.8   L
 7: 2012   1.8   L
 8: 2012   1.8   L
 9: 2012   5.5   M
10: 2013   1.0   L
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("Year   Value
2011   2.1
2011   2.1
2011   3.5
2011   7.8
2011   7.8
2012   1.8
2012   1.8
2012   1.8
2012   5.5
2013   1.0")
```

Comment: thanks for the solution! Received the error msg "Supplied 3 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 66 in column 'cat'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly."

Comment: There are cases with only 1 value. What would you like to assign for that?